# SQL query to select values grouped by hour(col) and weekday(row) based on the timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by, heatmap, weekday

I have searched SO for this question and found slightly similar posts but was unable to adapt to my needs.

I have a database with server requests since forever, each one with a timestamp and i'm trying to come up with a query that allows me to create a heatmatrix chart (CCC HeatGrid).

The sql query result must represent the server load grouped by each hour of each weekday.

Like this: [Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALPpO.png)

I just need the SQL query, i know how to create the chart.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those looks like "counts" of rows.

One of the issues is "sparse" data, we can address that later.

To get the day of the week ('Sunday','Monday',etc.) returned, you can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function. To get those ordered, we need to include an integer value 0 through 6, or 1 through 7. We can use an `ORDER BY` clause on that expression to get the rows returned in the order we want.

To get the "hour" across the top, we can use expressions in the SELECT list that conditionally increments the count.

Assuming your timestamp column is named `ts`, and assuming you want to pull all rows from the year 2014, we start with something like this:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(t.ts)
     , DATE_FORMAT(t.ts,'%W')

  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.ts >= '2014-01-01'
   AND t.ts <  '2015-01-01'
 GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(t.ts)
 ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(t.ts)
```

<strike>(I need to check the MySQL documentation, `WEEKDAY` and `DAYOFWEEK` are real similar, but we want the one that returns lowest value for Sunday, and highest value for Saturday... i think we want `DAYOFWEEK`, easy enough to fix later)</strike>

The "trick" now is the columns across the top.

We can extract the "hour" from timestamp using the `DATE_FORMAT()` function, the `HOUR()` function, or an `EXTRACT()` function... take your pick.

The expressions we want are going to return a 1 if the timestamp is in the specified hour, and a zero otherwise. Then, we can use a SUM() aggregate to count up the 1.  A boolean expression returns a value of 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

```
     , SUM( HOUR(t.ts)=0  )  AS `h0`
     , SUM( HOUR(t.ts)=1  )  AS `h1`
     , SUM( HOUR(t.ts)=2  )  AS `h2`
     , '...'
     , SUM( HOUR(t.ts)=22 )  AS `h22`
     , SUM( HOUR(t.ts)=23 )  AS `h23`
```

A boolean expression can also evaluate to NULL, but since we have a predicate (i.e. condition in the WHERE clause) that ensures us that `ts` can't be NULL, that won't be an issue.

The other issue we can encounter (as I mentioned earlier) is "**sparse**" data. To illustrate that, consider what happens (with our query) if there are *no*  rows that have a `ts` value for a `Monday`. What happens is that we don't get a row in the resultset for `Monday`. If it does happen that a row is "missing" for `Monday` (or any day of the week), we do know that all of the hourly counts across the "missing" `Monday` row would all be zero.